# Getting "PHP Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect." When uploading wordpress theme

Tags: php

I am uploading a bought theme to wordpress but keep getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(G:\localhost\root\website\wordpress/wp-content/plugins/G:/\localhost\root\website\wordpress/wp-content/themes/cacoon/inc/languages/portfolioposttype-en_US.mo) is not within the allowed path(s): (G:\localhost\root;C:\Windows\Temp\) in G:\\localhost\root\website\wordpress\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 457
```

The /root/website refers to the structure within the hosting account where i am hosting multiple sites within the same account ie. mainhostsite.com/otherSiteOnTheSameAccount.com

This is the statment on line 457:

```
if ( !is_readable( $mofile ) ) return false;

$mo = new MO();
if ( !$mo->import_from_file( $mofile ) ) return false;

if ( isset( $l10n[$domain] ) )
    $mo->merge_with( $l10n[$domain] );

$l10n[$domain] = &$mo;

return true;
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on what i need to do to fix this error? (Apologies if the way i have layed the question out is not the best, if someone could inform me on how to structure it properly it would be greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 17):

I fixed it by setting `none` in `open_basedir` in the PHP settings of my plesk panel.

Comment: life saver answer

Comment: Time saving answer.